# Copying a vector of vector of strings to a HTML file in the form of a table (in html) in C++

Tags: c++, html, c++11, c++14, ofstream

I've a C++ code, whose business logic generates a "vector of vector of strings"

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec2DTable;
```

I want to read each row i.e std::vector form this 2D vector and place it in a HTML file, using C++. Is there any C++ API to achieve this ?

I know I can do this using C++ file steam functions & indivisually write HTML tags etc.. But is there any advanced way of doing this using C++ (like C++ 11, C++14, 17 etc..).

```
HTMLWriter(std::vector<std::string> eachRow)
{
    WriteToHtmlInTableFormat(); // How do I implement this function in C++
}
```

Comment: Use [std::ofstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream).

Comment: Just write line for line to a file?

Comment: You probably want to pass `eachRow` by const reference.

Comment: There is nothing in standard C++ for manipulating HTML files, specifically (beyond generic I/O facilities that apply equally to all kinds of files). You'd either have to write your own, or look for a third-party library.